# Running Processing on Ubuntu : ./processing: 110: java: not found

Tags: ubuntu, processing

I am trying to run [processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, as a basic tutorial program. When I run the program in the terminal, I get the following error message:

`./processing: 110: java: not found`

I do not understand this error message.

I obtained the download from the following page:

https://processing.org/download

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be resolved by installing or updating java on your ubuntu system.

See: @ https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-java-ubuntu